# Why $\left(1 + xi \right)^n$ creates a spiral of right triangles?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I was wondering why the formula $\left(1 + xi \right)^n$ was creating a spiral of right triangles in the complex plane, and not $\left(2 + xi \right)^n$ for example.

Is there a specific reason for the binomial to have a left term of $1$?

For anyone wanting a clearer sight, here is what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: The triangle with vertices $0, 1, 1+xi$ is right-angled, but the triangle with vertices $0,1,2+xi$ isn't. Generally, the sequence $z^n$ generates a spiral of triangles similar to the triangle with vertices $0,1,z$. (For non-real $z$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I only consider the successive multiplication of complex numbers $n$-times.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is actually why I am trying to understand, why we need to start from a complex number $1 + xi$ where the real part is fixed at $1$.

Comment: The triangle with vertices $0, z^n, z^{n+1}$ is obtained from the triangle with vertices $0, z^{n-1}, z^n$ by a similarity transformation. The first triangle to consider is the one with vertices $0, z^0, z^1$. And that is right-angled if and only if $\operatorname{Re} z = 1$, $z$ is purely imaginary, or $z$ lies on the circle $\lvert w - 1/2\rvert = 1/2$..

Comment: @DanielFischer so why we need $z^0$ to be $1 + 0i$?

Comment: That is given. **Everything** to the power of $0$ is $1$.

Comment: Okay, that is what I was also thinking about. Thank you.